# talend: how to merge columns to one other

Tags: talend

I have one table:

```
|| id || val1 || val2 || val1-2 || val2-2 || val1-3 || val2-3 ||  
|  1   |  vv1  |  ww1  |   vv3   |   ww3   |   vv6   |   ww6   |   
|  2   |  vv2  |  ww2  |   vv4   |   ww4   |   vv7   |   ww7   |
```

And would like to have the following:

```
|| id || val1 || val2 ||
|  1   |  vv1  |  ww1  |
|  2   |  vv2  |  ww2  |
|  1   |  vv3  |  ww3  |         
|  2   |  vv4  |  ww4  |         
|  1   |  vv6  |  ww6  |         
|  2   |  vv7  |  ww7  |
```

So I would like to put the content of some columns under other columns.

Which talend component I can achieve this?

Comment: Thanks. Both solutions work. But the editing of tMap is more comfortable and I can add expression filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do this would be using tMap and while creating output group use "create join table from" option...see this link below http://garpitmzn.blogspot.in/2011/12/one-way-to-split-single-row-to-multiple.html

more details given below - (as very rightly pointed out by ydaetskcoR)

A similar example is given below - 
Say you have input data as

```
CountryName1      CountryCode1       CountryName2      CountryCode2
ABCDE              ABC                  XYZE             ZY
```

What you want is to split this single row into two rows as below

```
countryname        countrycode
ABCDE              ABC                  
XYZE                ZY
```

one quick solution incase you have requirement like above, where you know number of rows you want to split -
Take this row as input to tmap component and in tmap create one output group say out_1.
Now in this out_1 drag and link countryName1 and countryCode1 columns from input.
Now create another output group out_02 in this tmap and when "add a output" dialog comes
select "create join table from" and in the dropdown select out_1 group, so that our output rows from this out_02 group will also go to out_01 group. So our tmap will have only one output group out_01 containing rows from both out_01 and out_02. now in out_02 drag and link countryName2 and CountryCode2 columns.

[image: image1]
[image: image_2]
[image: image_3]

Answer (score 1):

You should use a tSplitRow for this purpose. Inside this component, define an schema with 3 fields. Then , in the Column mapping part, define 3 rows like that:

(supposing that you get a flow named row1 from the previous component)

```
row1.id | row1.val1   | row1.val2
row1.id | row1.val1-2 | row1.val2-2
row1.id | row1.val1-3 | row1.val2-3
```

And you have it!